Chromium apps are flickering on wayland
Arch Linux/Sway/Wayland
Nvidia gpu 3070 with proprietary driver 565.57.01
Running apps like chrome or vscode in native wayland mode
(with --ozone-platform=wayland flag) results in terrible flickering and glitching experience, albeit refresh rate is good (144 fps). When i run them on x11, I see no flickering, but fps is capped to 60.
I have tried --disable-gpu-compositing flag, and many others, but all of them seem to either cap frame rate or introduce flickering.
How do I solve this dilemma and is it even possible to solve?
